# Ошибка подключения компонентов Vue.js через CDN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Пишу обычный блог. Публичную часть сделал на PHP + JS, админку хочу написать PHP + Vue.js

Подключить через CDN не сложно, но как после этого подключать компоненты? При обычном подключении дает ошибку.

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Если прописать type="module", то

```
Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Видимо, должен быть другой ход. Долго бьюсь, не могу найти ответы на просторах интернета.

```
Файлы сейчас
ADMIN
 |__ admin.php
 |__ main.js
 |
 |__ components
      |__ App.vue
```

```js
// main.js
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            test: 11,
        }
    },
});

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<!-- admin.php -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>ADMIN PANEL</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{ test}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="/views/admin/main.js" type="module" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

При таком подходе можно использовать только inline-компоненты.

Чтобы использовать стандартные VUE-компоненты, нужно использовать WEBPACK (для сборки компонентов) или изначально запускать VUE-проект.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/728272)